# Going through a divorce and I’m in dire need of a new vehicle. Can I purchase one with a co-signer?

Tags: united-states, divorce

I’m currently going through a divorce in Mississippi. Non contested papers have been drawn up and sent to my wife. My vehicle has bitten the dust. Can I purchase a vehicle with a co-signer and keep it out of the divorce? If not can I purchase one once the papers are signed and filed but not finalized?

Comment: I think this is more of a legal question that a financial one. In any case I would not use a cosigner (search questions on this site for the reasons) - get the cheapest car you can afford on your own and save up for a better one...

Comment: You really have to specify your country for this question to be answered correctly.

Comment: +1 for "drive a junker until the divorce is settled". Or check what public transit exists in your area. Or bicycle -- the kiddie trailers often put out on the curbside can pretty trivially be fitted to carry cargo, and some can be used stroller-style without a bike, so that may be a viable option. Or rent when absolutely needed. Or combination of these. Or... point is, consider broaden your definition of adequate transportation for (hopefully) a short time.

Answer (score 4):

Talk to your lawyer about this issue. They can let explain how this would impact the process.

If by the use of the term uncontested divorce, you mean that you aren't using a lawyer then see if you can get access to an attorney for a consult via your employer, your church or some other organization you are a member of.

Regarding the use of a co-signer even if it doesn't complicate the process: the general advice is to never be a co-signer. The complexity of doing this during a divorce adds more risk; therefore you might have a hard time finding somebody to co-sign the loan.